# Adicionar dados no Firebase

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, firebase

Preciso de uma ajuda de depois pois estou com dificuldade na inserção de novos dados no firebase.

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo para meu TCC onde seja possível realizar um cadastro e assim que conseguir logar ter uma opção para adicionar mais dados do usuário. ex: Foto, apelido, telefone, etc..

A minha dificuldade é que sempre está criando uma nova chave no banco, não está adicionando os dados na tabela atual do usuário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que os dados (apelido, phone e profileImage) fique dentro de usuário que logou.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Use ```mUserdatabase.child("usuario").child(userId).setValue(instanciaDaSuaClasseUsuarioOuMapa)```

Comment: Então fiz do mesmo jeito que mencionou, porém quando instancio minha classe usuário apresenta erro.